# Vue js variable not working on page when running

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, vue.js

I want to use vue.json my asp.net mvc project. I downloaded vue.js from nuget package and drag into layout. When I run project it seems like this

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmKhn.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGRpN.png

or this
https://ibb.co/fMa2eU

this is source code layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        @RenderBody()

</body>
</html>
```

and this is index.cshtml code

```
<div id="#vueapp">
<input type="text" v-model="firstName"/>
    <p>{{ firstName }}</p>
</div>
<script>

    var mainvue = new Vue({
        el: "#vueapp",
        data: {
            firstName:"fasdfa",
        },

    })
</script>
```

I am wondering why its not working plzz help

Comment: When you say it's not working, what actually happens?  If you open your browser's developer tools > console, are there errors logged there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illegal syntax in your html code, you can't write `id="#vueapp"`, ommit the #, `id="vueapp"` and you should good to go. But keep `el: "#vueapp"`, that's how you refer to an id

Answer (score 0):

This could be taking place because of a 'wrongly dated script'.
You have got to know the latest version of Vue.js out there and use the correct script according to your project.

As of the time of this response:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

is the correct script for Vue 3.

However you can check the https://unpkg.com/ page in order to see what is the latest script out there, or test out the best fit for the node version you have gotten on your machine.

Peace!